# Automatically resize NSTabView to fit content view

Tags: resize, autoresize, nstabview

I have a NSTabView with a number of NSView items.  I want to resize the tab view so that the displayed view always fits snugly within the tab view.

I've tried a number of variations of setFrame within the tabView's delegate didSelectTabViewItem and shouldSelectTabViewItem but can't seem to get it to work.  I think I have to change the size of the tabView's contentRect, but this seems to be readonly.

Can anyone please give me a quick pointer to perhaps where this has been done before (I'm having no luck with Google).

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally got it:

1. In Xcode (.xib editor), check the Resize box [image: Resize box]
   of the container window
   [image: Window inspector]
2. Click on the "tabView" and check this [image: Autoresizes Subviews] here [image: Autoresizes Subviews panel]
3. At last simply adapt its resizing rules in the Size Inspector, that is![image: AutoSizing]